# stateChangeStart - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging

I am working with $stateChangeStart for login.

In my site I have some pages where user can go when he is not logged.

I write this code for logout and for check access on some page.

But I have problem when user go to page about (there is no need for user validation)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            console.log('TS', toState, 'TP', toParams, 'FS', fromState, 'FP', fromParams)
            if (!$rootScope.currentUser) {
                console.log('NO USER')
                if (toState.name !== 'login') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log('SOME ROUTE');
                    $state.go("login");
                }
                else if (toState.name !== 'about' ) {
                    console.log("about no user")
                    $state.go("about");
                }

            }
        });
```

Any idea how can I do that with $stateChangeStart

This with else if doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to specify on each route (at config time) if it requires a login,

```
.state("users", {
   url: "/users",
   data: {
      requiresLogin: true
   }
})
```

then you will able to check if the state requires login on each navigation, something like that:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) => { 
    if(toState.data && toState.data.requiresLogin) {
       // validate the user here, if not valid navigate to Login
    }
});
```

As a bonus, you can take advantage of data inheritance and specify a scope of routes that requires a login with an `abstract` state.

```
e.state("users", {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/users",
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    }
})
.state("users.main", {
    url: "/",
    template: '<users-main></users-main>'
})
.state("users.page2", {
    url: "/page2",
    template: '<users-page2></users-page2>'
})
```

In the example above, each state that is a child state of users (has `users.` prefix at its name) will inherit the data prop, therefore will require login.